# logging full SQL queries with triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to log the full SQL query of anything changing the value of one column from one pre-determined value to another pre-determined value. Unfortunately, it is unclear to me how to do this, if it even is at all.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set up an update trigger (after or before) on the table.

Then have logic (expressed as pseudo-code):

```
if old.col = 'Value1' and new.col = 'Value2'
then insert into logrecords(. . .) select "what I want to log here"
end if ;
```

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-proxy.html) can help you to get the query and you can write a filter to select queries only that are affecting specific rows.